# File.WriteAllText creates inaccessible files. "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Tags: c#, winforms

I have event that happens on a button press, that prompts the user for a folder directory, then prompts them to name and save a file within that directory. It also creates a `dictionary` with user generated information, and prints it into the saved file for later use:

```
        {
            {
                if (gunFolder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Properties.Settings.Default.currentGunPath = gunFolder.SelectedPath;
                }

                Dictionary<string, object> savedgun = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                    {
                        {"Ranged Weapon", txtRangedWeapon.Text }
                    };

                gunSave.FileName = txtRangedWeapon.Text;
                string path = Path.GetFullPath(gunSave.FileName);
                gunSave.InitialDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.currentGunPath;
                gunSave.Filter = "Json files | .json";
                gunSave.Title = "Save the Gun";
                if (gunSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(savedgun);
                    File.WriteAllText(path, json);
                }
            }
        }
```

Technically this code works, and I have used this method of in another part of the project to create functional .json files as well. For some reason I am unable to discern alone, the files produced by this example do not appear at the specified path instead appearing only in my PC's Quick Access menu in File Explorer.

The example should produce an accessible .json file at the path, rather attempting to open any file created with this specific example using VS 2022 produces the error: "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Comment: You should put `string path = Path.GetFullPath(gunSave.FileName);` **after** the `ShowDialog` call. Only so it could oick up the file name selected by the user.

Comment: Temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.